# CSS selector to find element whose one of subelements has particular text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xpath

CSS selector to find element where one of its subelements has a particular text value. ie:

```
<div id=some">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li ><a href="#>Home</a></li>
   <li ><a href="#">Val1</a></li>
   <li ><a href="#">Val2</a></li>
```

Here, I want to find the one `<li>`, having  with innerText = Val2

Comment: Please post your own solution, rather than leave the question open. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple substring match, use `:contains`:

```
 var li = $('#some li:contains("Val2")');
```

If you want exact (full text match), use a filter:

```
 var li = $('#some li').filter(function(){
     // return true to keep a match and false to ignore it
     return $(this).text() == "Val2";
 });
```

If you want case-insensitive full text matching, use a regex (with the `i` option) in a filter:

```
 var li = $('#some li').filter(function(){
     // return true to keep a match and false to ignore it
     return /val2/i.match();
 });
```

*The regex expression is probably wrong (I always mess them up first time), but you get the idea :)*

Comment: ok, 'filter' is ok idea, whereas ':contains' seems like being realy deprecated and not working - couldn't make it work in IE, at least. Finally, I used KO bindings, as that seeds easier than direct jq dom manipulatiions for sake I needed (initially, I thought jq would just be faster to do :) )

Comment: The *CSS* `:contains` selector may be deprecated, but the  `:contains` jQuery pseudo selector is not deprecated :) I would recommend one of the `filter` options anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just use the :contains pseudo selector:

http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/

Though as I read that link I realise that :contains is now deprecated. If you're using jQuery you could take a look at:

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

I stand to be corrected but using this selector in jQuery should work in any case.